# Build every branch but only those newly pushed to

Tags: jenkins, automation, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I want to have Jenkins CI test every branch but not all existing one, solely the ones which received a recent push.

I have set up a GitHub web hook which triggers new builds. This works fine for the branch specifier set to **master**. Now I tried ** so every branch is built.

The problem: on the first push it tries to build *every* branch, which is simply too much and would take ages. Is there a way to limit this?

Comment: Is there a naming convention for your branches? You could use it to filter branches?  Other than that options are limited.  You can trigger a dummy build and make it pass on every existing branches.  Then adjust the script to do the real build.

Answer (score 0):

There is no configuration which supports the feature you are requested and since it looks like there is no plugin yet. Your best shot would be to [implement your own plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial) that can specify a certain date threshold for branches.

Having said that, to solve your problem I would simply:

1. Empty the shell script for your job
2. Trigger a new build
3. Set your shell script again

This way all remote branches get checked out, run and marked as successful within no time due to the empty shell script. After re-enabling your actual shell script you are good to go.